# JAXB SCD not working with annox

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations, xjc, annox

I am having difficulties getting JAXB binding files to work with annox and SCD element selection. The schema is a bare basic schema with a ComplexType named SongType. I tried the normal way doing something like below and everything works a treat, class is named Song and not SongType and also has the Deprecated annotation.

`<jaxb:bindings node="/xsd:schema" schemaLocation="example.xsd">
      <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='SongType']">
        <jaxb:class name="Song"/>
        <annox:annotateClass>
          <annox:annotate annox:class="java.lang.Deprecated"/>
        </annox:annotateClass>
      </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>`

But when I try to the same with jaxb scd references, XJC just fails with a xerces exception complaining that it does not know about the annox element present. Can anyone offer a suggestion of what is wrong here?

`<jaxb:bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://www.fleurida.com/blueprint">
      <jaxb:bindings scd="~tns:SongType">
        <jaxb:class name="Song"/>
        <annox:annotateClass>
          <annox:annotate annox:class="java.lang.Deprecated"/>
        </annox:annotateClass>
      </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>`

Error Trace:

```
[INFO] Parsing input schema(s)...
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/dev/oss/jaxb-scd-annox-problem/src/main/resources/scd.annox.jaxb.xml{8,25}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/dev/oss/jaxb-scd-annox-problem/src/main/resources/scd.annox.jaxb.xml; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 25; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'annox:annotateClass'.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1906)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:746)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:570)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.util.ForkContentHandler.startElement(ForkContentHandler.java:114)
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner$LocationResolver.startElement(DOMForestScanner.java:147)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:244)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:127)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan(DOMForestScanner.java:92)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet$Target.apply(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:184)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet$Target.applyAll(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:142)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet$Target.apply(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:163)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet$Target.applyAll(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:142)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet$Target.access$700(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:86)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet.apply(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:241)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:541)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:378)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:174)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:58)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:44)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:29)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:364)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

A fully documented and runnable example on [github](https://github.com/bertramn/jaxb-scd-annox-problem)

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on there, but thank you for suggesting this problem will go away if I stop using SCD for annotating elements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to an issue in XJC, as reported [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-1047).

In short, Annox uses vendor extensions (i.e. special configuration elements like `annox:annotate`) which are currently not supported in SCD-based bindings.

Unfortunately, I don't believe this will be fixed any time soo. Please use `node` bindigs instead.

BTW, I have moved Annox to GitHub as well:

- https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin
- https://github.com/highsource/annox

You can now annotate in Java syntax:

```
<xsd:complexType name="FooType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <annox:annotate>@java.lang.SuppressWarnings({"unchecked","rawtypes"})</annox:annotate>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence> ...</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```